# Dynamic index array angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have variable like below

```
$scope.priceOption = [];
$scope.priceOption['flip'] =            {
    dbvalue: "option:flip",
    caption:"反転図面の作成",          
    price:{TN:100,
           UR:200,
           HD:300}
};
$scope.priceOption['car'] =         {
    dbvalue: "option:car", 
    caption:"植栽・自動車・外構の追加", 
    price:{TN:100,
           UR:200,
           HD:300}
};
var price_type="HD";
```

How can I get price with dynamic price_type in HTML?

```
<label>{{priceOption['car'].price[price_type]}}円</label>
```

// expect value is 300円, if price_type = "HD";

Comment: What is price_type? Kindly describe the question. I think its partially written.

Comment: `priceOption['handwritten'].price[price_type]` should work...

Comment: Please check the variable, you will see price with 3 types {TN, UR, HD}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var price_type="HD";` to `$scope.price_type="HD";`. The view doesn't see the variable you pass to binding.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use $scope.price_type="HD" instead of var price_type="HD"
>   because you can not access javascript variable in view other than
>   declared with $scope